# Can I use Windows Environment Variables into Eclipse Workspace path?

Tags: eclipse, path, environment-variables

When you start Eclipse for the first time, it asks you the path for the workspace. Now, normal path should be `C:\Users\USERNAME\Workspace` but, if I try to set `%USERPROFILE%\Workspace` it doesn't work, it creates a folder called `%USERPROFILE%\Workspace` under the Eclipse folder.

So the question is: how to use windows environment variables to specify workspace path? Thank you.

P.S: I know that Eclipse has got customizable environment variables but I didn't try them and I want to use them neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `eclipse.exe -data %USERPROFILES%\myCustomWorkspaceDir` to have the workspace in your wanted sub directory. In this case, you will not even get the dialog asking for the workspace.

There are still more [runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) for Eclipse.

Comment: Should I change my eclipse shortcut on the desktop to run this command everytime I start eclipse? Or is for the first time only?

Comment: Eclipse remembers the last used workspace. So if you don't have multiple workspaces, you don't need this at all. If you work with multiple workspaces however, this is the most effective way of easily starting Eclipse with the wanted one by creating multiple desktop shortcuts pointing to the different workspaces.

Comment: What about the external libraries path? Should I copy my libraries into the workspace or is there a way to use environment variables for them?